# SSM parameter in cli is evaluating string as an api request

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssm

I am trying to store an ssm parameter using AWS cli

`URL='https://gatewayurl.com/dev'`

`aws ssm put-parameter --name "/dev/app/HOSTNAME" --value $URL --type String --overwrite`

SSM parameter is being uploaded however it does not store value `https://gatewayurl.com/dev`. Insteads it stores the value `Hello World` which is the response for the URL provided. Is there a way that I can store the URL as a string without it being evaluated as a HTTP request and thus string the response instead of the URL?

Answer (score 0):

To define a variable in bash should use `URL` not `$URL`.

For url values, you need to use json way of providing params:

```
URL='https://gatewayurl.com/dev'

json_params='{' 
json_params+='"Name": "/dev/app/HOSTNAME",'
json_params+='"Value": "'${URL}'",'
json_params+='"Type": "String",'
json_params+='"Overwrite": true'
json_params+='}'


aws ssm put-parameter --cli-input-json "${json_params}"
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53092997/saving-a-url-to-aws-parameter-store-with-aws-cli).

Answer (score 0):

I've just bumped into this one - there is special handling in the CLI to treat URL values as a feed, you can disable it by running this before your command `aws configure set cli_follow_urlparam false`. The information is hard to find and hidden away in the documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html#general-options